# How to efficiently convert dates in numpy record array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to read a very large (1.7 million records) csv file to a numpy record array. Two of the columns are strings that need to be converted to datetime objects. Additionally, one column needs to be the calculated difference between those datetimes.

At the moment I made a custom iterator class that builds a list of lists. I then use np.rec.fromrecords to convert it to the array.

However, I noticed that calling datetime.strptime() so many times really slows things down. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do these conversions. The times are accurate to the second within the span of a date. So, assuming that the times are uniformly distributed (they're not), it seems like I'm doing 20x more conversions that necessary (1.7 million / (60 X 60 X 24).

Would it be faster to store converted values in a dictionary {string dates: datetime obj} and first check the dictionary, before doing unnecessary conversions?

Or should I be using numpy functions (I am still new to the numpy library)?

Comment: Can you tell us what date format is used within the csv file? I would assume that a `fromfunction()` could help here, but I need slightly more info.

Comment: If all of those are within a single day than it should be easy to make the conversion somewhat simpler. You only need to parse the date once. After that you simply convert the seconds like this: `lambda x: int(x[-11:-9]) * 3600 + int(x[-8:-6]) * 60 + int(x[-5:-3])`

Comment: How long does it take to process the entire csv file?

Comment: Around two minutes with the current design.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems to me like your issue is having repeated occurrences, thus doing the same conversion more times than necessary.  **IF** that interpretation is correct, the most efficient method would depend on how many repeats there are.  If you have 100,000 repeats out of 1.7 million, then writing 1.6 million to a dictionary and checking it 1.7 million times might not be more efficient, since it does 1.6+1.7million read/writes. However, if you have 1 million repeats, then returning an answer (O(1)) for those rather than doing the conversion an extra million times would be much faster.

All-in-all, though, python is very slow and you might not be able to speed this up much at all, given that you are using 1.7 million inputs.  As for numpy functions, I'm not that well versed in it either, but I believe there's some good documentation for it online.

Comment: The dates (accurate to a second) only exist on 1 day. Hence maximum of 86,400 dates. Right now the application is doing 3.4 million conversions. I do acknowledge that the dictionary method will almost certainly speed it up a lot. I'm primarily consulting stack to see if they are other ways I have not thought of (or something in numpy).

Comment: Ahh ok I see, in that case, I would agree that, IMO, a dictionary is the fastest way.  I doubt numpy has a way to do it, and there may be very convoluted methods that could give better results, but weighing all the factors, a dictionary is probably best.